# Different result when executed from Crontab

Tags: linux, cron, lsof

I am trying to get the number of open files periodically through crontab using lsof|wc -l.
It always returns zero. It is giving correct result when i run it directly.Any idea about this strange behaviour?Is it related to pipe size as the result can be quite large?Thanks a lot.

Kaka

Comment: How does your crontab line look like?

Comment: The cron job is running as the same user you try 'directly'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is the environment variables.

In this case it might be the PATH. lsof is often found in or /usr/sbin , that might be in your PATH when you run it interactivly, while not in the PATH when run from cron.

try `/usr/sbin/lsof|wc -l` in your cron script. And check the local mail, as cron output is normally sent there, there might be relevant error messages.

> Is it related to pipe size as the result can be quite large?

No.

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks.. my bad,i failed to think of it :)